# Definite integral for exp(+/- i ax)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Is the following correct?

$$\begin{align}
 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\, e^{+iax} &=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\,\cos{(ax)}+i\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx\,\sin{(ax)}\\\\ 
&\overbrace{=}^{x=-y}\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} d(-y)\,\cos{(a(-y))}+i\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}d(-y)\,\sin{(a(-y))}  \\\\
&=\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d{y}\,\cos{(ay)} -i\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d{y}\,\sin{(ay)}}_{-\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}}\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d{y}\, e^{-iay}\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d{x}\, e^{-iax}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: The integral dose not exist in any sense if $a$ is  real number

Comment: Must be evaluated in the sense of distributions.  As Kavi remarked, it does not converge in the usual sense.  As illustrated in the OP: do not try to use the normal integration rules on divergent integrals.

Comment: My recommendation is to first make the integral convergent. This can be done by multiplying the integrand by a Gaussian with a large width. All your steps then become legitimate. At the end you may take the limit of the width of the Gaussian to infinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object written $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\pm iax}\,dx$ is either $(i)$ a divergent integral or $(ii)$ tempered distribution and not an integral.

---

It is easy to see from even-odd symmetry that for any $L\in \mathbb{R}$ $\int_{-L}^L e^{+ iax}\,dx=\int_{-L}^L e^{- iax}\,dx$, but the limit as $L\to \infty$ of both of these integrals fails to exist (unless the limit is a distributional limit).

However, if we interpret the object as a tempered distribution, then it is, in fact, the Fourier Transform of the constant $1$.  **And in this case (i.e., in distribution) that the equality $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{+iax}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-iax}\,dx$ holds.**

---

**EVALUATION OF $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\pm iax}\,dx$**

If we interpret the object as a Fourier Transform, we can evaluate it as follows.  Let $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$ (i.e., a Schwarz Space Function).  Then, invoking the Fourier Inverse Theorem, we have

$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{1\}, \phi\rangle&=\langle 1, \mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)e^{\pm iax}\,dx\,da\\\\
&=2\pi \phi(0)\tag1
\end{align}$$

Hence, in distribution we see from $(1)$ that $\mathscr{F}\{1\}=2\pi \delta$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac Delta distribution.

**Note that we have tacitly shown that the equality $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{+iax}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-iax}\,dx$ holds in distribution.**

---

---

**ALTERNATIVE DEVELOPMENT:**

Here, we represent the Fourier Transform of $1$ as the distributional limit $\displaystyle \lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{-L}^L e^{\pm iax}\,dx$.  Proceeding, we have for any $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$

$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{1\}, \phi\rangle&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x) \int_{-L}^L e^{\pm iax} \,da\,dx\tag2\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x) \frac{2\sin(Lx)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\text{IBP}}-\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(x) \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{2\sin(x'L)}{x'}\,dx'\,dx\\\\
&=-\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(x) \int_{-\infty}^{Lx} \frac{2\sin(x')}{x'}\,dx'\,dx\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\text{DCT}}-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(x) \lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{Lx} \frac{2\sin(x')}{x'}\,dx'\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(x) 2\pi H(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-2\pi \int_0^\infty \phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=2\pi \phi(0)
\end{align}$$

from which we deduce that in distribution

$$\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-L}^L e^{\pm iax}\,dx=2\pi \delta(a)$$

where the limit is taken as in $(2)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I was actually looking for something that would show that the equality holds. My steps are not valid for a divergent integral. Can you please suggest a reference which I can cite? I am from a physics background, so not sure where exactly I might find a good discussion: fourier analysis, complex analysis? Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.  Gelfund and Shilov is a great book on the theory of generalized functions.